# Should we cancel the applicationScope created in the Application class?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I've created an applicationScope in my Android Application class for operations that should outlive the viewModelScope and the lifecycleScope, like this:

```
class App : Application() {
    val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(...)
```

Should we automatically cancel the applicationScope in order to avoid leaks or for other reasons? I'm asking because I've seen some projects where people would call

```
applicationScope.cancel()
```

when their main activity would be destroyed or when the user wants to close the app. Is this necessary in some scenarios?

Comment: I don’t think so. If someone is tearing it down when the main activity is destroyed they should have just used the lifecycle scope of that activity. When the application is destroyed, the whole application is being torn down and reclaimed by memory so there is nothing more to do. The only reason to create an application scope is for tasks that should not be cancelled before the application is fully destroyed. It’s up to you not to reference items in a coroutine that should not be allowed to live for as long as the coroutine might take to finish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to cancel an application level scope. It will be torn down when the process is killed. [Source](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/coroutines-patterns-for-work-that-shouldnt-be-cancelled-e26c40f142ad)

```
class MyApplication : Application() {
  // No need to cancel this scope as it'll be torn down with the process
  val applicationScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob() + otherConfig)
}
```

> We don’t need to cancel this scope since we want it to remain active as long as the application process is alive, so we don’t hold a reference to the SupervisorJob. We can use this scope to run coroutines that need a longer lifetime than the calling scope might offer in our app.